# Check if a new pull request was created

Tags: github-api-v3

Is it possible to check every `x` seconds and determine if a new pull request was created on a github repository, and perform a function on it (I am using the JavaScript library `@octokit/rest`)?

So far I have

```js
const { Octokit } = require('@octokit/rest');

const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: "REDACTED"
});

var data = (async () => {
    var response = await octokit.request('/repos/foo/bar/pulls?state=all');
    return response;
})();
```

with data as the response of the github api. How do I determine if a new pr was created, the easiest way I figure out is ofc to actually compare the length of the variable `data`, but so far I couldn't actually figure out how to do so.

Comment: PRs have numbers that always increment. So you could record the highest number and see if any is now higher.

Comment: Isn't there an inbuilt function in the library which could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `pulls` sorts by `created`, so we can check to see if the 0th index has a `number` property greater than the old `number`. (the `number` is like #1, #4, etc. that shows up on the website). During the time that we're waiting for a new PR, multiple PR's could be made, so we need to filter out `data` so that we can have multiple PR's above the previous value.

This was based off of the documentation:

- https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#pulls-list
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-pull-requests

and testing the routes with curl

```js
const { Octokit } = require('@octokit/rest');

const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: "REDACTED"
});

const getData = () => octokit.request('/repos/foo/bar/pulls?state=all');
const getLatestPRNumber = (data) => data.length === 0 ? 0 : data[0]["number"];
const getPRsAboveNumber = (data, prNumber) => data.filter(({number}) => number > prNumber)

(async () => {
    const data = await getData();
    let latestPR = getLatestPRNumber(data);
    setInterval(async () => {
        const data = await getData();
        const firstPRNumber = getLatestPRNumber(data);
        if (firstPRNumber > latestPR) {
            const newPRs = getPRsAboveNumber(data, latestPR);
            console.log(newPRs);
            latestPR = firstPRNumber;
        }
    }, 1000 * 60); // 1000ms * 60 = 60s
})();
```

If too many PR's are made, then some PR's wouldn't be accessible since the GitHub API using pagination

Per the documentation:

| Name | Type | In | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| per_page | integer | query | Results per page (max 100). Default: 30 |
| page | integer | query | Page number of the results to fetch. Default: 1 |

Comment: Instantly exits; Doesn't work even on creating a PR.